# Twitter Bootstrap - semantic way using "container-fluid" just on lg devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

Let's say I have a div where I have applied "container-fluid".

How can I change it to "container" when the viewport is below 1200px (large devices) ?

I know that I can duplicate the code and use something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid hidden-md">...content here...</div>
<div class="container hidden-lg">...content here...</div>
```

But this doesn't feel good. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom class and media query to your own stylesheet (loaded after bootstrap), so something like

```css
.customcontainer {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
@media(max-width:1200px) {
  .customcontainer {
    max-width: 300px; //or whatever you want max width to be
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid customcontainer">...content here...</div>
```

I just added the border and low px width for demonstration purposes